# How to access Fragment views from Activity using DataBinding?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-databinding

This is the layout file for the MainActivity:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
</layout>
```

This container holds the HomeFragment:

```
class HomeFragment: Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val dataBinding = inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        return dataBinding.root
    }
}
```

Which has this layout:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/home_fragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_container">

        <include
            layout="@layout/layout_auth"
            android:id="@+id/auth_layout"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Now, in my MainActivity I can access the `navHostFragment` using data binding:

```
dataBinding.navHostFragment
```

But this line :

```
dataBinding.navHostFragment.homeFragment
```

Nor this line:

```
dataBinding.navHostFragment.mainContainer
```

Nor this line:

```
dataBinding.navHostFragment.authLayout
```

Cannot be accessed. How to access `homeFragment` or `mainContainer` or `authLayout` that exist in the fragment from the MainActivity using data binding?

Comment: you can not access it data binding only binds views in the layout. why you even want to access views of fragment from Activity ? if you want to communicate b/w Activity and fragment for this there are other ways . like a shared VM or an interface .

Comment: @ADM I see, thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access it data binding only binds views with in the layout. If you want to communicate b/w Activity and fragment for this there are other ways like a shared ViewModel or an interface.